# Function "collect_vertex_marginals" returns an error on documentation example

Tags: python-3.x, graph-tool

I am trying to reproduce an example from the graph-tool documentation on network reconstruction. I noticed that the code changed recently and although it used to return no error before, it now does.

I am running Python 3.6.5 with the graph-tool installed through Docker on Windows OS. Specifically, I have tried running the below code:

```py
1 def collect_marginals(s):
2   global pv, u, cs
3   u = s.collect_marginal(u)
4   bstate = s.get_block_state()
5   b = gt.perfect_prop_hash([bstate.levels[0].b])[0]
6   pv = bstate.levels[0].collect_vertex_marginals(pv, b=b)
7   cs.append(gt.local_clustering(s.get_graph()).fa.mean())
```

The error message that I get is:
"TypeError: collect_vertex_marginals() got an unexpected keyword argument 'b'"

In the previous version of the function which was running successfully:

a) 'collect_vertex_marginals' in line 6 did not have the 'b' argument

b) line 5 of the above code did not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an older version of the library. You must upgrade to the newest release.